# How to execute a django or SQL query after clicking the toggle button?

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

I have two tables:

```
class DibbsSpiderDibbsMatchedProductFieldsDuplicate(models.Model):
    nsn = models.TextField()
    nsn2 = models.TextField()
    cage = models.TextField()
    part_number = models.TextField()
    company_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    supplier = models.TextField(db_column='Supplier', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    cost = models.CharField(db_column='Cost', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    list_price = models.CharField(db_column='List_Price', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    gsa_price = models.CharField(db_column='GSA_Price', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    hash = models.TextField()
    nomenclature = models.TextField()
    technical_documents = models.TextField()
    solicitation = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    purchase_request = models.TextField()
    issued = models.DateField()
    return_by = models.DateField()
    file = models.TextField()
    vendor_part_number = models.TextField()
    manufacturer_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    product_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'dibbs_spider_dibbs_matched_product_fields_duplicate'


class DibbsSpiderSolicitation(models.Model):
    line_items = models.IntegerField()
    nsn = models.TextField()
    nomenclature = models.TextField()
    technical_documents = models.TextField()
    purchase_request = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'dibbs_spider_solicitation'
```

I want to display these in the format :

[image]

The original link is on : http://develop-330.gsa-cs.com/test/

After Clicking on the toggle button, how to execute the query ?

Line #1 means Line line_items

First row is of first table.

After clicking on the toggle, I want to execute a django query or a sql query which joins two tables since they have common nsn.

`nsn` is common on both the tables.

If there are more line items , the joined query should repeat.

code of button:

```
<td onclick="showHideRow('switch_1');">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse"></button>
                     </td>
```

Comment: Which toggle button are you referring to ?

Comment: there is a button i have pasted the code

Comment: I don't understand after clicking of button you want do joins of table and then ?

Comment: and display the joined table.

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute sql query in the html file. if you want  to do this, you can add a new url in `urls.py` and a function in `views.py` to send the  join table query and then return the result.

You can do this by `ajax GET request`(in the ajax success function you can add or replace the data received from `view.py` with the current data in html) In jQuery you can wait for the toggle event, after clicking the toggle button you can send a ajax request to the url.